# VBA Macro to subtract dates by duplicates ID

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I would like to create a Macro in VBA to identify the first date and the last date by ID and then get the subtract result between them formatted in hours.

This is an example of my Table:

```
 ID         DATE   
 001        11/11/2013 
 001        11/21/2013
 001        11/25/2013
 002        12/04/2013
 002        12/05/2013
 003        12/05/2013
 001        11/23/2013
```

The desired result:

```
 ID         DATE           RESULT IN HOURS (Last Date - First Date)
 001        11/11/2013     =(11/25/2013)-(11/11/2013)
 001        11/21/2013
 001        11/25/2013
 002        12/04/2013     =(12/05/2013)-(12/04/2013) 
 002        12/05/2013
 003        12/05/2013
 001        11/23/2005
```

In the current table, there are 2 or more duplicates IDs with different Dates as you can see in the 001 ID Sample.

My first solution was sorting the table by ID and Date and then apply a Countif formula to get the duplicates IDs but I was only able to identify the First Date by ID and missing the Last Date.

I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: you can get the last date using a max if formula: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/

Comment: Are you useing tables in excel or access? In accesss I would use a Query-based solution, in excel you would have to 'walk' through the table. Two very different beasts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice problem. I like the use of collections, because they are quite fast. There must be numerous ways solve a problem like this, the following is one example:

```
Sub jzz()
Dim cArray() As Variant
Dim lastRow As Long

Dim rw As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim firstDate As Date
Dim lastDate As Date
Dim id As Long
Dim idColl As Collection

Set idColl = New Collection

'determine last row:
lastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

'if you plan to loop the cells repeatedly,
'the use of an array to hold cell values pays off, performancewise
cArray = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 2)).Value

For rw = 1 To lastRow
    id = Cells(rw, 1)
    'determine if id is used or not:
    For i = 1 To idColl.Count
        If idColl(i) = id Then GoTo nextRow
    Next i
    'id is not in collection, add it:
    idColl.Add id
    firstDate = cArray(rw, 2)
    lastDate = 0
    'loop array to find first and last dates:
    For i = LBound(cArray) To UBound(cArray)
        If cArray(i, 1) = id Then
            If cArray(i, 2) < firstDate Then firstDate = cArray(i, 2)
            If cArray(i, 2) > lastDate Then lastDate = cArray(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print id, firstDate, lastDate
nextRow:
Next rw
End Sub

Private Function TimeDiffHours(T0 As Date, T1 As Date) As String
'function that returns the difference between T0 and T1 in hours:mins
TimeDiffHours = Int((T1 - T0) * 24) & ":" _
                & Format(Round(((T1 - T0) * 24 - Int((T1 - T0) * 24)) * 60, 0), "00")
End Function
```

Note that this only finds the first and the last dates for each id and prints it out, along with the time difference in Hours:mins. It does nothing with it, not even save results. That is up to you now.

Comment: Great solution. I add the following lines to your code to get the results:                                                              Cells(rw, 3).Value = id
Cells(rw, 4).Value = firstDate
Cells(rw, 5).Value = lastDate                                                      However I got some errors for the Firt date by ID. It gets the first date of the first ID for each ID. I've been crazy trying to fix it but I coudn't find the solution. The last date by ID is working just perfect.

Comment: Change firstDate  = cArray (1, 2) into firstDate = cArray (rw, 2). I think that should do it. I will check later, as I am on my phone right now.